# MySQL Database User Permissions

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm designing this application and I'm having a hard time understanding the correct or acceptable way to do the permissions.
The application is for gate access control, it will have two types of users, a supervisor and a security guard. The security guard should only be able to view and add visitors and the supervisor can perform all the CRUD operations.
The part I'm having trouble understanding is the permissions part. Will the permissions be set on the apps code in or will it be set on MySQL.
How would I accomplish this the easiest and least complex way?

Comment: You must use Roles. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html. It's better to handle permission in app and db, but handling is db is necessary.

Comment: @majidhajibaba that's not true at all. It's usually not very feasible to use database roles for application access control. You may have different database roles for different applications or in the most extreme case maybe two roles for the same app, if their workload and usage is completely different, but mostly you will have access control in the application and the database role being used is the same for all operations.